# AngularJS DI with different modules

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am having some issues trying to use the Angular dependency injection with different modules. At the moment, I have the following. In my `index.html`, the files are loaded in the following order (end of `<body>` tag):

1. `network.js`
2. `authentication.js`
3. `login.js`
4. `app.js`

---

`network.js`

```
angular.module('services.network', [])
  .factory('Network', ['$http', '$state', function ($http, $state) { ... }]);
```

---

`authentication.js`

```
angular.module('services.authentication', ['services.network'])
  .factory('Authentication', ['$state', 'Network', function ($state, Network) { ... }]);
```

---

`login.js`

```
angular.module('controllers.login', [])
  .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) { ... }]);
```

---

`app.js`

```
var app = angular.module('parkmobi', [
    'ngRoute',
    'services.network',
    'services.authentication',
    'controllers.login'
]);

app.run(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    $rootScope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function () {
        $(document).foundation('reflow');
    });
}])

app.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider

    .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/login.html',
        controller: 'LoginCtrl'
    });
}]);
```

---

Up until this point, everything seems to be quite happy. Now, however, I want to use the `Authentication` service in the `LoginCtrl`, which I would have thought is done as follows:

`login.js`

```
angular.module('controllers.login', ['services.authentication'])
  .controller('LoginCtrl', ['$scope', 'Authentication', function ($scope, Authentication) { ... }]);
```

However, this causes the following injection error:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=%24stateProvider%20%3C-%20%24state%20%3C-%20Authentication
R/<@http://localhost/testapp/vendor/angularjs/angular.min.js:6:417
```

Comment: Is there a reason for using multiple modules? Normally you just define one module and everything feeds off there. Then you need only inject your dependencies straight into `controller` functions.

Comment: how come `$stateProvider` error comes as you are using `$routeProvider`

Comment: This is just how I got used to using it from working through the Ionic Framework tutorials. Maybe I'm coming from the wrong way around, as I now want to use angular vanilla for web applications. Will give it a try quickly.

Comment: @NicoHuysamen do look at my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error came because you've injected `$state` provider in your `Authentication` factory, without having `ui.router` module in `app.js` `parkmobi` module.

It should use `$route` instead of `$state` as your are doing your route in angular-router.

```
angular.module('services.authentication', ['services.network'])
  .factory('Authentication', ['$route', 'Network', function ($route, Network) { ... }]);
```

Or if you want to use `ui-router` then you need to use `$stateProvider` while registering `state`s & `ui.router` module should be include in your app.

Comment: Spot on, just had to replace $state with $router in the Network service also. Thanks!